# Adjusting images to the same height in a horizontal scroll area works with Chrome, but not with Firefox and Safari: Why?

Tags: css

I coded this, and it works the way I need it with Chrome:

```css
.image_gallery_container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.image_gallery {
  background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.image_gallery_items {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image_gallery_item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.image_gallery_item_image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image_gallery_item_image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.image_gallery_item_description {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="image_gallery_container">
  <div class="image_gallery">
    <div class="image_gallery_items">
      <div class="image_gallery_item">
        <div class="image_gallery_item_image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/1599px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg?20190920093216" />
        </div>
        <div class="image_gallery_item_description">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="image_gallery_item">
        <div class="image_gallery_item_image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/1599px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg?20190920093216" />
        </div>
        <div class="image_gallery_item_description">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="image_gallery_item">
        <div class="image_gallery_item_image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/1599px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg?20190920093216" />
        </div>
        <div class="image_gallery_item_description">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="image_gallery_item">
        <div class="image_gallery_item_image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/1599px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg?20190920093216" />
        </div>
        <div class="image_gallery_item_description">Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But Safari and Firefox messes it up completely. I think they can't deal with the `flex: 0 0 auto;`. Is there a simple way to fix that? Maybe just adding one CSS rule?

Here is a JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lp754wme/

Comment: When `flex-shrink: 0` is applied, Firefox is apparently using the intrinsic width of the image (1599px) as the width of its container and not shrinking the container to fit its contents as rendered. This seems to be related to not having a fixed width defined for the image or any parent element of the gallery.